# Change the size of the gutter of an MDC layout grid using a SASS Mixin

Tags: sass, material-components-web

I'm attempting to change the size of the gutter of an MDC Material Components web layout grid using a SASS Mixin and failing!

At present I'm using:

```
.mdc-layout-grid-cell
 {   
   @include mdc-layout-grid-cell('desktop', 3, 60px);
 }
```

I can see the mixin is being used...however the gutter stays steadfast the same size.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-post from discussion on [MDC Web's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1879):

The reason the mixin doesn't appear to do anything is because it sets the correct property value, but then immediately overrides it with a CSS variable for browsers that support it.

However, we never update the value of the CSS variable, so modern browsers continue to render the inherited value instead.

E.g. ([source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/31aa2888b28cd95add6a8fd92ce20aed7c9c17c2/packages/mdc-layout-grid/_mixins.scss#L119-L120)):

```
// We could set --mdc-layout-grid-gutter-#{$size} to $gutter here...
grid-gap: $gutter;
grid-gap: var(--mdc-layout-grid-gutter-#{$size}, $gutter);
```

This is a [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1879) that we plan to fix at some point. Community help is always welcome!

Comment: Thanks Andy based on Rusteems post I figured there might be a bug there.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, MDC-Web's cell class should be `mdc-layout-grid__cell` instead of `mdc-layout-grid-cell`:

```
.mdc-layout-grid__cell {   
   @include mdc-layout-grid-cell('desktop', 3, 60px);
 }
```

Additionally, you need to specify CSS variable to modify the gutter:

```
:root {
  --mdc-layout-grid-gutter-desktop: 60px;
}
```

But using a mixin can create extra CSS, and if you want to avoid that, you can modify the Layout Grid with [Sass variables](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-layout-grid/_variables.scss). You need to set this variable in your main `.scss` file with modified values before `@import`ing the Layout Grid:

```
// Gutter size
$mdc-layout-grid-default-gutter: (
  desktop: 24px,
  tablet: 16px,
  phone: 16px
);

@import "@material/layout-grid/mdc-layout-grid";
```

It's also worth mentioning that you can override any Sass variable which is defined in the MDC-Web codebase with a `!default` flag.

Comment: Thanks Good catch.  However... still not working.  The middle value for number of columns seems to be adjusting the number of columns the cards are spread across correctly.  However the gutter size just doesn't seem to change.  However using the sass variables as you've suggested does seem to work.

Comment: It seems like you also need to specify a CSS variable to modify the gutter, I'll update the answer.